Simplifying removable discontinuity $\frac{1}{\sin{(2\pi x)}\Gamma(x-\frac{1}{2})}$
Show that $\frac{1}{\sin{(2\pi x)}\Gamma\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)} = -\frac{\Gamma(2(1-x))\Gamma(x)}{4^{1-x}\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}} \tag{*}$
for $x \in (0,1)$.
I am aware of properties of Gamma function such as \begin{gather}2^{2z-1}\Gamma(z)\,\Gamma(z+\frac{1}{2})=\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(2z) \tag{1} \\ \Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin{\pi z}} \tag{2}\\ \Gamma(-z) = -\frac{\pi}{z\Gamma(z)\sin{\pi z}}\tag{3}\end{gather}.
However, I am unable to reach to the final required form. Any hints?
Note: I have the left hand side (in (*)) in a numerical algorithm, which I am trying to simplify so that it doesn't return NaN.

Got a proof with the help of a friend. Starting from the left side \begin{align*} \frac{\Gamma(x)}{\sin{(2\pi x)}\left[\Gamma(x)\Gamma(x-1/2)\right]} &\overset{(1)}{=} \frac{\Gamma(x)}{4^{1-x}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi} \sin{(2\pi x)}\Gamma(2x-1)}\\ 
&= \frac{\Gamma(x)}{4^{1-x}\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}} \left[\frac{\pi }{\sin{(\pi (2x))}}\right]\frac{1}{\Gamma(2x-1)} \\
&\overset{(2)}{=}\frac{\Gamma(x)}{4^{1-x}\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}  \frac{\Gamma(2x)\Gamma(1-2x)}{\Gamma(2x-1)} \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(x)}{4^{1-x}\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}}  (2x-1)\Gamma(1-2x) \\
&= -\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(2-2x)}{4^{1-x}\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}} \end{align*}
